# Re-projection in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms, coordinate-system

I have published a layer on Geoserver by cascading a remote WMS. i have successfully got all the layers from remote wms and publish one of those layers. But I want to re-project the layer from its native srs wgs84 to declared srs EPSG 3011. But when i displayed this layer in my openlayers application, it did not displayed. Then i go back to geoserver and change the declared srs to wgs84 as well, this time the layer displayed successfully. 
my question is, why the layer not re-projected ?. OR is there any other way to re-project the layer other than mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using the force SRS box for that - Tell GeoServer what the projection of the layer really is and then let GeoServer handle the reprojection for you when you make the request.

Comment: How good is this reprojection? e.g. from 4209 to 4326 there are ~10 options for reprojection depending on location. How does geoserver decide which one to use?

Comment: @OliverBurdekin - please ask a new question so there is room to answer